# How to insert new data before old data rather than after

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I perform the php script to show random data. I use ajax get to get data from the php script and continue getting data from the php script every 1 seconds. I also perform removal of the last row if the count is more or eqaul to 4. HOwever, my output is backward. I want to append new data before old data.

php script

```
<?php


$countryarr = array("UNITED STATES", "INDIA", "SINGAPORE","MALAYSIA","COLOMBIA","THAILAND","ALGERIA","ENGLAND","CANADA","CHINA", "SAUDI ARABIA");
$length = sizeof($countryarr)-1;
$random = rand(0,$length);
$random1 = rand(0,$length);

$random_srccountry = $countryarr[$random];
$random_dstcountry = $countryarr[$random1];
echo "<div>[X] NEW ATTACK: FROM [".$random_srccountry."] TO [".$random_dstcountry."]  </div>";
?>
```

html code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Add new data</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
#result {
    width: 500px;
    height:500px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
var $auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
    var $count = $('#result div').length;

    while ($count >= 4) {
    $('result div:last-child').remove();
    $count = $('#result div').length;
    }
    updateServer();
}, 1000);
//Remove last div if the count is more than 4
function updateServer() {
    $.get({
            url: 'randomData.php',
            dataType: 'text',
            success: randomdata
        });
}

function randomdata(val) {
        $('#result').append(val); //i want to insert before in other words new data appear at the top and old data remain down
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I thought of using before or insertbefore to insert new data before the old data. I also used node to insert before.It does not work. Please help me. thank you..

Comment: try prepend instead of append

Comment: `$('#result').prepend(val);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) from jquery :

```
function randomdata(val) {
    $('#result').prepend(val);
}
```

**EDIT**

I noticed an other error : `$('result div:last-child').remove();` should be `$('#result div:last-child').remove();`

That's probably why it don't change, when it's at 4 divs it doesn't delete and redo the count, so you get stuck inside the while ... The fix from below should solve the problem

Comment: it works but however, once the count is 4 rows. the content does not change at all. i dont see any new data...

Comment: @Azhar might have something to do with your `while ($count >= 4)`.

Comment: i want to acheive something like this https://www.fireeye.com/cyber-map/threat-map.html

Comment: is that very difficult?

Comment: I noticed an other error : `$('result div:last-child').remove();` should be `$('#result div:last-child').remove();`

Comment: That's probably why it don't change, when it's at 4 divs it doesn't delete and redo the count, so you get stuck inside the while ... The fix from below should solve the problem